# Query for new replies on a comment table?

Tags: php, mysql, comments

I have a standard comment_id/comment_parent_id setup on my mysql comments table (with a created timestamp).

My question is what is the least process intensive query to get all NEW replies on a user's comment?  Just like with the commenting systems that use a checkbox to email replies to your comment?

Do you cookie a timestamp for last login?  Update a last login table?

I guess I'm looking to understand how to retrieve the starting point so I can alert users of replies to their replies.

Sorry if my explanation is cryptic.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly I will store the user wish to get a notification on a reply to his/her comment, by doing so when a new comment is posted I just check with a simple query if the parent comment needs a notification and I can even expand it to check if the writer of the content also wants a notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a "post_last_viewed_by_user" column (hopefully with a better name).  Then, when the user visits the post:

```
SELECT
   comment
FROM
   comment.comment c
   JOIN posts USING p (post_id)
   JOIN user_post_views u USING (user_id)
WHERE
   user_id = ?
   AND c.comment_time > u.post_last_viewed_by_user
```